# cplexAPI 1.4.0 installiation on R4.0.3

Tags: r, compilation, cplex, rtools

Im trying to install cplexAPI 1.4.0 on R4.0.3. I have followed all the steps as described and have installed cplex 12.10

However I still get the following errors:

> "C:/Source/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc  -I"C:/Source/R/R-40~1.3/include"
> -DNDEBUG -g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include"         -O2
> -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c cplexAPI.c -o cplexAPI.o C:\Program
> Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:243:62:
> error: expected ')' before 'deprecated'  #      define
> CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
> ^~~~~~~~~~ C:\Program
> Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1194:1:
> note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
> CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ C:\Program
> Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:243:41:
> error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token  #      define
> CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
> ^~~~~~~~~~ C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1194:1:
> note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
> CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ C:\Program
> Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:243:62:
> error: expected ')' before 'deprecated'  #      define
> CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
> ^~~~~~~~~~ C:\Program
> Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1200:1:
> note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
> CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ C:\Program
> Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:243:41:
> error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token  #      define
> CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
> ^~~~~~~~~~ C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1200:1:
> note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
> CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ C:\Program
> Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:243:62:
> error: expected ')' before 'deprecated'  #      define
> CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
> ^~~~~~~~~~ C:\Program
> Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1231:1:
> note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
> CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ C:\Program
> Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:243:41:
> error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token  #      define
> CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
> ^~~~~~~~~~ C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1231:1:
> note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
> CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ C:\Program
> Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:243:62:
> error: expected ')' before 'deprecated'  #      define
> CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
> ^~~~~~~~~~ C:\Program
> Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1237:1:
> note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
> CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ C:\Program
> Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:243:41:
> error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token  #      define
> CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
> ^~~~~~~~~~ C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1237:1:
> note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
> CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ C:\Program
> Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:243:62:
> error: expected ')' before 'deprecated'  #      define
> CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
> ^~~~~~~~~~ C:\Program
> Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1242:1:
> note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
> CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ C:\Program
> Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:243:41:
> error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token  #      define
> CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
> ^~~~~~~~~~ C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1242:1:
> note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
> CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ C:\Program
> Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:243:62:
> error: expected ')' before 'deprecated'  #      define
> CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
> ^~~~~~~~~~ C:\Program
> Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1597:1:
> note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
> CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ C:\Program
> Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:243:41:
> error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token  #      define
> CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
> ^~~~~~~~~~ C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1597:1:
> note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
> CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ make: ***
> [C:/Source/R/R-40~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf:222: cplexAPI.o] Error 1
> ERROR: compilation failed for package 'cplexAPI'
>
> - removing 'C:/Source/R/R-4.0.3/library/cplexAPI' Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘cplexAPI’ had non-zero
>   exit status

has anyone come across this before?